# Fetching rows within set time constraints

Tags: sql, sqlite, datetime

The table:

```
trips
----
id, signin, first_name, last_name, ~~
id, signin, first_name, ~~~
etc, etc..
```

The query I've got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(SELECT date(signin,'weekday 0','-7 day') ) as start_of_week,
(SELECT date(signin,'weekday 0','-1 day') ) as end_of_week
FROM trips
```

Returns the first and last day of each row's signin field as start_of_week and end_of_week.

Runs just fine.

But when I try to run more advanced queries to simply count the many rows in between the the start_of_week and end_of_week it returns the total count instead, inaccurate dates, ignores the other week's patterns found. I tried fooling with order by and group by but I want to understand where I'm going wrong rather than just playing with values.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(SELECT date(signin,'weekday 0','-7 day') ) as start_of_week,
(SELECT date(signin,'weekday 0','-1 day') ) as end_of_week,
COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM trips
GROUP BY date(signin) BETWEEN start_of_week AND end_of_week
```

start_of_the_week being Sunday
end_of_the_week being Saturday

Is the groundfloor I keep finding myself at. This one only returns one of the weeks start-end with the total count of them all, and it returns it twice rather than distinctively. I'm working in SQLite.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
date(signin,'weekday 0','-7 day') as start_of_week,
date(signin,'weekday 0','-1 day') as end_of_week,
COUNT(*) as total_rows
FROM trips
GROUP BY start_of_week, end_of_week
```

Pulls what I need.